# How to use Sony Xperia Z in Eclipse(ADT Bundle) for USB Debugging

Tags: android, eclipse, driver, sony-xperia

I am new to android development and i want to use my Sony Xperia Z for debugging purposes. But I am unable to use that. I have downloaded Google Usb Driver from SDK Manager and tried to update from device manager but it says driver is already up to date . I am using Windows 8.1 Pro. Also i tried to Xperia Z driver downloaded from Sony's Website. But still I am getting the same message "Driver is up to date" Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Tap the Build number 7 times  - in Settings --> About Phone. This should enable developer options. I'm sure I had issues like this before!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I have Found the solution.I did is :
1.Download the driver from Sony's Website.
2.I inserted a SD card into my device and switch to MSC from Settings>Xperia Connectivity> USB Connectivity > USB Connection Mode > MSC
3.Enabled The USB Debugging form Settings
4.Connected the device to PC and then ALertDialog will appear in Your Device. Press Yes. You are done.